# Why navigator.geolocation.watchposition not work in setInterval()?

Tags: react-native

*I try to get location coordinate every 1 sec. But `geolocation.watchposition` not work in `setInterval`*

**here is my code:**

```
componentDidMount(){
  const intervalId = BackgroundTimer.setInterval(() => {
          navigator.geolocation.watchPosition((position) => {
        console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        var lat = parseFloat(position.coords.latitude);
        var lng = parseFloat(position.coords.longitude);

          console.log("lat :",lat);
          console.log("lng :",lng);
    });
  }, 1000);

  BackgroundTimer.clearInterval(intervalId);
}
```

*if I remove `BackgroundTimer.setInterval` method. It gives me coordinates. But I want everysecond*

Answer (score 0):

The watchPosition method will automatically call the `success` callback as soon as the user's position has changed, so doing this won't work. If you really need to get every second (which you might not need as user's position rarely will change in 1 second and it consumes a lot of battery power) you use the setInterval using along with `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` method.

Comment: Actually I want to get location when user change position. But I couldnt handle that